# no puedo encontrar un elemento en selenium python

Tags: python, web, selenium

ya lo inspeccione e intente todos los metodos, por id, clase, xpath etc y me es imposible localizar este elemento, es un cuadro de texto para crear un email, este es mi codigo

```
class generador_correos:
def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(
        executable_path=r"C:\Users\erick\Documents\selinium\drivers\geckodriver.exe")
    self.driver.get("https://protonmail.com/es/")
    time.sleep(2)


def generar_correo(self):
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"]/ul/li[8]/a').click()
    time.sleep(1.5)
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="signup-plans"]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/p').click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_id("freePlan").click()
    time.sleep(10)

#----es este elemento el de la linea de aca abajo el no puedo encontrar----
    usuario1 = self.driver.find_element_by_id("username")
    usuario1.send_keys("hola")


bot = generador_correos()
bot.generar_correo()
```

creo que el error se encuentra en que es un elemento dentro de otro elemento, ya que al inspeccionar puedo ver que esta en unión con el elemento de alado, pero en verdad no se, si alguien me puede ayudar estaría agradecido

Comment: Puedes hacer el siguiente ejercicio: con la extensión para  chrome de selenium graba una macro y ve que código se guarda, ahí podrás tener acceso al elemento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El elemento que estás buscando está dentro de un iframe y para ello se ocupa `switch_to`

```
time.sleep(10)
self.driver.switch_to.frame(self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
#----es este elemento el de la linea de aca abajo el no se podía encontrar----
usuario1 = self.driver.find_element_by_id("username")
usuario1.send_keys("hola")
#----aprovechamos de hacer otras cosas dentro del iframe y salimos---
self.driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: uf muchas gracias amigo